# Delete duplicated fields in Array of Hashes Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-hash

I have a Array of Hashes that have JSONs with duplicated fields and I want to delete the duplicated ones:

```
[ {
  "code" : "32F",
  "lon" : 0.963335,
  "fint" : "2022-05-03T13:00:00",
  "prec" : 0.0,
},{
  "code" : "32F",
  "lon" : 0.963335,
  "fint" : "2022-05-03T13:00:00",
  "prec" : 0.0,
},{
  "code" : "90X",
  "lon" : 0.963335,
  "fint" : "2022-05-03T13:00:00",
  "prec" : 0.0,
}]
```

This is the wished output:

```
[{
  "code" : "32F",
  "lon" : 0.963335,
  "fint" : "2022-05-03T13:00:00",
  "prec" : 0.0,
},{
  "code" : "90X",
  "lon" : 0.963335,
  "fint" : "2022-05-03T13:00:00",
  "prec" : 0.0,
}]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: The fact that the elements of the array are hashes is irrelevant. The answer is the same for the array `[1, 2, 2, 4]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have wrong syntax

`"code" : "32F",` -- you don't need whitespace here

Right variant is `"code": "32F",`

And you even don't need quotes here. Just `code: "32F",`

To **delete** duplicates from array -- use `uniq!`

Be careful

```
ary = [1, 1]
ary.uniq! # => [1]
ary # => [1]


ary = [1, 2]
ary.uniq! # => nil
ary # => [1, 2]
```

Or use `uniq` without bang to return new array

```
ary = [1, 1]
ary.uniq # => [1]
ary # => [1, 1]


ary = [1, 2]
ary.uniq # => [1, 2]
ary # => [1, 2]
```

In your case

```
ary =
  [{
    code: "32F",
    lon: 0.963335,
    fint: "2022-05-03T13:00:00",
    prec: 0.0,
  },{
    code: "32F",
    lon: 0.963335,
    fint: "2022-05-03T13:00:00",
    prec: 0.0,
  },{
    code: "90X",
    lon: 0.963335,
    fint: "2022-05-03T13:00:00",
    prec: 0.0,
  }]

ary.uniq!
# => [{:code=>"32F", :lon=>0.963335, :fint=>"2022-05-03T13:00:00", :prec=>0.0}, {:code=>"90X", :lon=>0.963335, :fint=>"2022-05-03T13:00:00", :prec=>0.0}]
```

Comment: Thanks, this work for JSON fields I posted. But If i have elements with same ```name``` and diferent ```lon``` how should do it?

Comment: There is no `name` in your example. You can use `uniq` with block: `ary.uniq { |hash| hash[:name] }`

Comment: @YungSifilis if you have such elements, it's unclear which of the different `lon` values you want to keep. Or maybe you want to calculate an average in that case. Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: @YungSifilis `uniq` with block will keep first duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Try uniq from the enumerables module. It should work natively for your use case.
It's available by default with a ruby array.

Answer (score -1):

use `.uniq` this should work for you.
NB: Your array of hashes having additional space after each key. You should remove it.